# What is the format for '2015-10-01T12:00:00.000-03:00' in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanna convert '2015-10-01T12:00:00.000-03:00' varchar into date in Oracle, like this:

```
select 
    to_date('2010-12-14:09:56:53', 'YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI:SS') - 
    to_date('2010-12-14:09:56:46', 'YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI:SS') 
from dual;
```

but for that format.

Please if the question is unclear, say me why and I'll give more information, don't negative me I'm noob :). 
Obs: I am using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` and if you want to convert it to a date then you can convert it to one time zone (typically `UTC`) and then `CAST` it to a date:

```
SELECT CAST(
         TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
           '2015-10-01T12:00:00.000-03:00',
           'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZR'
         )
         AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
         AS DATE
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select to_timestamp('2015-10-01T12:00:00.000-03:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3"Z"')
from dual;
```

Comment: sadly it gives me this error:
ORA-01861:
01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
*Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
           the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
           "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
           with no extra whitespace.
*Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.

Comment: "Z" means UTC time which is definitely not `UTC-03:00`